# Escape single quote inside double quote for executing a command in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```
function install_rubygems {
    #install rubygems
    ruby_cmd=("sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3"
     "bash -c 'curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io|bash -s stable'"
     "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"
     #"rvm install 1.9.2 --with-zlib-directory=/usr/local/rvm/usr --with-openssl-directory=/usr/local/rvm/usr"
     #"rvm --default use 1.9.2"
     #"gem install soap4r-ruby1.9 log4r net-ldap json httpclient"
  )
for cmd in  "${ruby_cmd[@]}"
do
  $cmd
  exit_status=$?
  if [ "$exit_status" -ne "0" ]; then
     echo "Error occured while running: $cmd. Exiting..."
     exit
  fi
done
}
```

I want to execute commands listed in ruby_cmd array one by one and then check the exit status of each and perform some operation after that. But when I execute the above script in shell it gives the error as below:

-sSL: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-sSL: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I am pretty new to shell scripting, could anyone please tell me what is the correct way to write above command?
PS: command is correct and it executes properly if directly run on bash

Comment: BashFAQ #50 is your friend; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general discussion of the topic, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

There are several approaches available:

#### Use a function

```
install_rubygems() {
  sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 && \
    curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable && \
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
)

install_rubygems || {
  retval=$?
  echo "Error occurred while running; exiting..." >&2
  exit "$retval"
}
```

---

#### Use an eval-able array

This is safe **only** if none of your strings can contain user-input. Otherwise, it opens you to shell injection attacks.

```
install_rubygems=(
  "sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3"
  "curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable"
  "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"
)
for cmd in "${install_rubygems[@]}"; do
  eval "$cmd" || {
    retval=$?
    echo "Error occurred while running $cmd; exiting..." >&2
    exit "$retval"
  }
done
```

---

#### Use multiple single-command arrays

Because each array here has only a single simple command -- no pipelines, no indirections, no substitutions performed at evaluation time -- it's somewhat more secure than the `eval` approach: Only places where it's explicitly running code through expansion (like the argument to `bash -c` or to an explicit `eval`) are prone to undefined behavior, so you could safely use untrusted data in other locations (such as the argument to `--keyserver`) with confidence that the shell won't do anything untoward with it, even if that data is attempting a shell injection attack.

```
install_rubygems_01=( sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 )
install_rubygems_02=( eval 'curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable' )
install_rubygems_03=( source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh )

for varname in "${!install_rubygems_@}"; do

  # there's a safer way to do this in bash 4.3, but that's not widely deployed yet
  # (this particular command shouldn't ever be unsafe unless varname has been tampered
  # with, but it had to be constructed very carefully).
  eval "cmd=( \"\${$varname[@]}\" )"

  ## ...specifically, in bash 4.3, you could do this instead of the above eval:
  #declare -n cmd=$varname

  # evaluate array as an exact argv
  "${cmd[@]}" || {
    retval=$?
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"
    echo "Error occurred while running ${cmd_str% }; exiting..." >&2
    exit "$retval"
  }

  ##Using bash 4.3 namevars instead of the eval above, you'd want to do this here:
  #unset -n cmd
done
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I did it with eval-able way. Worked like charm. Hope you had a great breakfast ;)

Comment: @rohitvyawahare, I did, thanks! And I've added the multi-single-command in, making the answer now complete. Notably, that third way requires the `bash -c` approach you were trying in your original code, since it's directly executing a single command and so doesn't parse compound commands such as pipelines, shell constructs like redirections, etc -- but this is also what can make it safer when using untrusted content to construct [carefully-chosen] parts of that array.

Comment: [You could use user content for the argument to `--keyserver`, for instance, and not worry about `http://$(rm -rf $HOME)/` being used as input -- which would be a very big worry if it were present in one of the strings being `eval`'d].